# use iptables for transparent access to 2 proxies depending on domain

Tags: iptables, proxy, http, transparent-proxy, socks

I have a setup where I have 2 proxy servers. One is a socks proxy which I wish to use for ALL connections by default. The second proxy is an http proxy which I wish to use for http connections to specific hosts (all on the same domain(s))

Lets assume:

- Socks proxy is hostA:9000
- Http  proxy is hostB:8080
- Domain that should go through http proxy is *.foobar.com

Can iptables be configured to do this?

Comment: I don't think there is any way you would be able to do this.  When your browser is talking socks, it is using a different protocol from an HTTP proxy.  Is there some reason why you don't do something in the browser with a proxy switcher or a PAC file?

Comment: Simple answer: Chrome. Chrome uses system proxy, which means one or the other.

Comment: How does Chrome's use of the system proxy have anything to do with what I asked or with iptables?

Comment: @exodist Chrome no longer uses the system proxy. It used to but recent versions are capable of using its own proxy. Proxy SwitchySharp (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dpplabbmogkhghncfbfdeeokoefdjegm) uses this to set up URL pattern based proxy switching.

Answer (score 1):

For the socks proxy you can use a utility called [`tun2socks`](http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/wiki/tun2socks) (thats a link). It basically sets up a tunnel device which you can create routing rules to tunnel your traffic through. I use this for connecting to my network at work (since the proprietary vpn software on linux is crap). It works just fine with a few quirks (most notable is that it works for TCP only).

For the http proxy. In theory this should be possible, but I've never done it myself. However nixcraft has a [howto](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-setup-transparent-proxy-squid-howto.html), and their stuff is usually pretty good.

Comment: Hi. I'm the author of tun2socks. Could you please provide some more details on those few quirks, maybe I can do something about them? I am already planning to add proper UDP support using the SOCKS UDP ASSOCIATE feature.

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak the other one that springs to mind is getting 'connection refused' (or other error) on the remote end, but getting 'connection closed' on the local end. I understand the reason for it, which is why I say 'quirk' instead of 'bug' :-)

Comment: I see, thank you. Though the SOCKS protocol does return error codes, and if I delay accepting the connection (replying the SYN) until I get a response from SOCKS, in case of error I may be able to reply with an appropriate error back to the client instead of accepting.